# How to Check the List is Present in the SharePoint online Site

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom

How to Check if the List is present in SharePoint online site?
in CSOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the PnP Core CSOM library, for SharePoint Online operation. Please find more details here - [SharePoint Online List Operations Using PnP Core CSOM Library - Part Two](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/sharepoint-online-list-operations-using-pnp-core-csom-library-part-two/)

```
 // Input Parameters  
    string siteUrl = "https://nakkeerann.sharepoint.com";  
    string userName = "abc@nakkeerann.onmicrosoft.com";  
    string password = "***";  

    // PnP component to set context  
    AuthenticationManager authManager = new AuthenticationManager();  

    try  
    {  
        // Get and set the client context  
        // Connects to SharePoint online site using inputs provided  
        using (var clientContext = authManager.GetSharePointOnlineAuthenticatedContextTenant(siteUrl, userName, password))  
        {  
            // List name input  
            string listName = "TestList";  
            // Checks the list exists  
            bool listExists = clientContext.Site.RootWeb.ListExists(listName);  
            if (listExists)  
            {  
                Console.WriteLine("List is available on the site");  
            }  
            else  
            {  
                Console.WriteLine("List is not available on the site");  
            }  
            Console.ReadKey();  
        }  
    }  
    catch (Exception ex)  
    {  
        Console.WriteLine("Error Message: " + ex.Message);  
        Console.ReadKey();  
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Create Client Context of your site then use below code:

```
ListCollection listCollection = clientContext.Web.Lists;

clientContext.Load(listCollection, lists => lists.Include(list => list.Title).Where(list => list.Title == "Your List Name"));

clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

if (listCollection.Count > 0)
{
    Response.Write("List all ready exist...");
}
else
{
    Response.Write("List not exist");
}
```

Reference Link: [Check List exist or not using CSOM](http://www.enjoysharepoint.com/Articles/Details/check-if-list-already-exists-or-not-using-sharepoint-2013-500.aspx)

Comment: what the heck... lists does not have a `Where` in my CSOM nuget package.

Comment: Please add LINQ DLL reference for Where

Comment: ok i will try that